# How to use self-built Electron binaries with electron-builder

Tags: binary, electron, electron-builder

I've built my own Electron binaries. I've put those binaries into `./node_modules/electron/dist`. Everything works fine when running the app with `npm start` from the development environment, but when packaging the app with electron-builder, Electron lacks that functionality that I added. It looks like electron-builder does not take whats in `node_modules/electron` when packaging an app.

Can somebody tell how I can use own Electron binaries with electron-builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved by using the `electronDist` property in the electron-builder's `build` section  of `package.json`.